# EmguCV (OpenCV) ORBDetector finding only bad matches

Tags: c#, opencv, feature-detection

### Problem

So I am fairly new to Computer Vision in general. I am currently trying to calculate a homography by analyzing 2 images. I want to use the homography to correct the perspective of 1 image to match the other. But the matches I am getting are just bad and wrong. So the homographic warp I do is completely off.

### Current state

I am using EmguCV for wrapping opencv in C#.
I got as far as that my code seems to work "properly".

I load my two images and declare some variables to store calculation artifacts.

```
(Image<Bgr, byte> Image, VectorOfKeyPoint Keypoints, Mat Descriptors) imgModel = (new Image<Bgr, byte>(imageFolder + "image0.jpg").Resize(0.2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Area), new VectorOfKeyPoint(), new Mat());
(Image<Bgr, byte> Image, VectorOfKeyPoint Keypoints, Mat Descriptors) imgTest = (new Image<Bgr, byte>(imageFolder + "image1.jpg").Resize(0.2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Area), new VectorOfKeyPoint(), new Mat());
Mat imgKeypointsModel = new Mat();
Mat imgKeypointsTest = new Mat();
Mat imgMatches = new Mat();
Mat imgWarped = new Mat();
VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch();
VectorOfVectorOfDMatch filteredMatches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch();
List<MDMatch[]> filteredMatchesList = new List<MDMatch[]>();
```

Notice that I use a `ValueTuple<Image,VectorOfKeyPoint,Mat>` to store the images directly with their respective Keypoints and Descriptors.

After this is use an ORB detector and BruteForce matcher to detect, describe and match the keypoints:

```
ORBDetector detector = new ORBDetector();
BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher(DistanceType.Hamming2);

detector.DetectAndCompute(imgModel.Image, null, imgModel.Keypoints, imgModel.Descriptors, false);
detector.DetectAndCompute(imgTest.Image, null, imgTest.Keypoints, imgTest.Descriptors, false);

matcher.Add(imgTest.Descriptors);
matcher.KnnMatch(imgModel.Descriptors, matches, k: 2, mask: null);
```

After this I apply the [ratio test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197091/how-does-the-lowes-ratio-test-work) and do some further filtering by using a match-distance threshold.

```
MDMatch[][] matchesArray = matches.ToArrayOfArray();

//Apply ratio test
for (int i = 0; i < matchesArray.Length; i++)
{
  MDMatch first = matchesArray[i][0];
  float dist1 = matchesArray[i][0].Distance;
  float dist2 = matchesArray[i][1].Distance;

  if (dist1 < ms_MIN_RATIO * dist2)
  {
    filteredMatchesList.Add(matchesArray[i]);
  }
}

//Filter by threshold
MDMatch[][] defCopy = new MDMatch[filteredMatchesList.Count][];
filteredMatchesList.CopyTo(defCopy);
filteredMatchesList = new List<MDMatch[]>();

foreach (var item in defCopy)
{
  if (item[0].Distance < ms_MAX_DIST)
  {
    filteredMatchesList.Add(item);
  }
}

filteredMatches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch(filteredMatchesList.ToArray());
```

Disabling any of these filter methods isn't really making my results much better or worse (just keeping all matches) but they seem to make sense so I keep them.

In the end I calculate my homography from the found and filtered matches then warp the image with this homography and draw some debug images:

```
Mat homography = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(imgModel.Keypoints, imgTest.Keypoints, filteredMatches, null, 10);
CvInvoke.WarpPerspective(imgTest.Image, imgWarped, homography, imgTest.Image.Size);

Features2DToolbox.DrawKeypoints(imgModel.Image, imgModel.Keypoints, imgKeypointsModel, new Bgr(0, 0, 255));
Features2DToolbox.DrawKeypoints(imgTest.Image, imgTest.Keypoints, imgKeypointsTest, new Bgr(0, 0, 255));
Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(imgModel.Image, imgModel.Keypoints, imgTest.Image, imgTest.Keypoints, filteredMatches, imgMatches, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255));

//Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ImageViewer.Show(imgKeypointsModel, "Keypoints Model"));
//Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ImageViewer.Show(imgKeypointsTest, "Keypoints Test"));
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ImageViewer.Show(imgMatches, "Matches"));
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ImageViewer.Show(imgWarped, "Warp"));
```

**tl;dr**: ORBDetector->BFMatcher->FilterMatches->GetHomography->WarpPerspective

### Output

[image: Example for the algorithm]
Example for the algorithm

[image: Test whether projection is going wrong]
Test whether projection is going wrong

[image: Using crosscheck when matching]
Using crosscheck when matching

Original images are 2448x3264 each and scaled by 0.2 **before** running any calculations on them.

### Question

Basically it's as simple yet complex as: What am I doing wrong?
As you can see from the example above my method of detecting features and matching them just seem to work extremely poorly. So I am asking if someone can maybe spot a mistake in my code. Or give advice on why my results are so bad when there are hundreds of example out on the internet showing how it works and how "easy" it is.

**What I tried so far:**

- Scaling of the input images. I generally get better results if I scale them down quite a bit.
- Detect more or less features. Default is 500 which is used currently. Increasing or decreasing this number didn't really make my results better.
- Various numbers of k but anything else except k = 2 doesn't make any sense to me as I don't know how to modify the ratio test for k > 2.
- Varying filter parameters like using a ratio of 0.6-0.9 for the ration test.
- Using different pictures: QR-code, Silhouette of a dinosaur, some other random objects I had lying around my desk.
- Varying the re-projection threshold from 1-10 with any changes in the result
- Verifying that the projection itself is not faulty. Feeding the algorithm with the same image for model and test produce the homography and warp the image with the homography. Image should not change. This **worked as expected** (see example image 2).
- Image 3: Using crosscheck when matching. Looks a lot more promising but still not really what I am expecting.
- Using other distance Methods: Hamming, Hamming2, L2Sqr (others are not supported)

**Examples I used:**

- https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher
- https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html
- https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/ (where I got the main structure of my code)

**Original Images:**
The original images can be downloaded from here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nlqv_0sH8t1wiH5PG-ndMxoYhsUbFfkC

### Further Experiments since asking

So I did some further research after asking. Most changes are already included above but I wanted to make a separate section for this one.
So after running into so many problems and seemingly nowhere to start I decided to google up the [original paper on ORB](http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf). After this I decided to try and replicate some of their results. Upon trying this I realised that even I try to match the match image rotate by a degree the matches seem to look fine but the transformation completely breaks down.
[image: Rotation]

Is it possible that my method of trying to replicate the perspective of an object is just wrong?

### MCVE

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17DwFoSmco9UezHkON5prk8OsPalmp2MX
(without packages, but nuget restore will be enough to get it to compile)

Comment: have you tried to reduce the RANSAC reprojection threshold in the GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures function? you have it in 10, maybe something like 3-5 makes more sense? Have you tried to select four points in both images manually? to kind of rule out that the matching is the problem... However, in a closer inspection I do not see 4 good matches in your image

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this in the question yes I did vary the reproduction threshold. Running it with 1-10 doesn't give me any distinguishable results by looking at the results with the human eye. Regarding the second point I did have one pair of images where I was able to extract 4 good matches but still the projection was off warping the image in a strange way.

Comment: I am going to try to feed the algorithm with the same image for model and test and see if i can get the projection to simply reproduce that image.

Comment: in the bfmatcher you can try to also put the crosscheck in true, this sometimes help more than the filters :)

Comment: I have updated the post to include the results of crosschecking. Looks very promising. Now opencv throws an exception when calculating the homography and im not sure why. ~~First im gonna try to reduce the matches maybe it's just too much with 296 matches.~~ well that wasn't the problem still crashing at 53

Comment: Got crosscheck to work and updated my post. It's still sadly not really doing a good job at matching.

Comment: Have you tried other distance functions like L2 or L2Sqr or maybe just Hamming but without the 2 (not sure what is the difference between the two Hammings though) ?

Comment: I have bumped into these problems in the past and I would suggest using [UnsharpMask](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15176/sharpening-an-image-using-emgu) before doing keypoint detection. Additionally, using Gaussian Blur might help. As you already mentioned, you tried to make changes to [default parameters of ORB](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/db/d95/classcv_1_1ORB.html), try playing with the parameters especially _scaleFactor_, _edgeThreshold_ and _patchSize_. If you can upload the original images, I can try to work it out.

Comment: Generally, if you have a lot of letters, I'd suggest using [FAST](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html#fast) instead.

Comment: @RickM. I tried using FAST for detection and BRISK for description before but they seem to not cooperate at all. A lot of times I get massive matches from a corner in the model image to points in the test image etc so i switched to ORB. thanks for the tipps im gonna try the pre processing steps and see if i can get anywhere with further parameter experimentation. Also I have updated to post and added a download for the original images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

### Problem 1

The biggest problem was actually a quite easy one. I had accidentally flipped my model and test descriptors when matching:

```
matcher.Add(imgTest.Descriptors);
matcher.KnnMatch(imgModel.Descriptors, matches, 1, null);
```

But if you look at the documentation of these functions you will see that you have to add the model(s) and match against the test image.

```
matcher.Add(imgModel.Descriptors);
matcher.KnnMatch(imgTest.Descriptors, matches, 1, null);
```

### Problem 2

I don't know why by now but `Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures` seems to be broken and my homography was always wrong, warping the image in a strange way (similar to the above examples).

To fix this I went ahead and directly used the wrapper invoke to OpenCV `FindHomography(srcPoints, destPoints, method)`. To be able to do this I had to write a little helper to get my data-structures in the right format:

```
public static Mat GetHomography(VectorOfKeyPoint keypointsModel, VectorOfKeyPoint keypointsTest, List<MDMatch[]> matches)
{
  MKeyPoint[] kptsModel = keypointsModel.ToArray();
  MKeyPoint[] kptsTest = keypointsTest.ToArray();

  PointF[] srcPoints = new PointF[matches.Count];
  PointF[] destPoints = new PointF[matches.Count];

  for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
  {
    srcPoints[i] = kptsModel[matches[i][0].TrainIdx].Point;
    destPoints[i] = kptsTest[matches[i][0].QueryIdx].Point;
  }

  Mat homography = CvInvoke.FindHomography(srcPoints, destPoints, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HomographyMethod.Ransac);

  //PrintMatrix(homography);

  return homography;
}
```

## Results

Now everything works fine and as expected:
[image: Result]

Comment: Amazingly detailed question & answer, I did notice that Emgu's GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures is broken and produces a weird bad result. However even with using your GetHomography method, the final image generated isn't perfectly rotated either. I tried some way around by sorting matches by distance aswell but wasn't successful. Cod's Answer above works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem and found a suitable solution this: [github Emgu.CV.Example DrawMatches.cs](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/blob/master/Emgu.CV.Example/FeatureMatching/DrawMatches.cs) in which everything works.

I modified the code and method `FindMatch` 
**looks like that:**

```
public static void FindMatch(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints, out VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints, VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches, out Mat mask, out Mat homography)
{
    int k = 2;
    double uniquenessThreshold = 0.80;
    homography = null;
    modelKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
    observedKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
    using (UMat uModelImage = modelImage.GetUMat(AccessType.Read))
    using (UMat uObservedImage = observedImage.GetUMat(AccessType.Read))
    {
        var featureDetector = new ORBDetector(9000);
        Mat modelDescriptors = new Mat();
        featureDetector.DetectAndCompute(uModelImage, null, modelKeyPoints, modelDescriptors, false);
        Mat observedDescriptors = new Mat();
        featureDetector.DetectAndCompute(uObservedImage, null, observedKeyPoints, observedDescriptors, false);
        using (var matcher = new BFMatcher(DistanceType.Hamming, false))
        {
            matcher.Add(modelDescriptors);

            matcher.KnnMatch(observedDescriptors, matches, k, null);
            mask = new Mat(matches.Size, 1, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
            mask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(255));
            Features2DToolbox.VoteForUniqueness(matches, uniquenessThreshold, mask);

            int nonZeroCount = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(mask);
            if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
            {
                nonZeroCount = Features2DToolbox.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(modelKeyPoints, observedKeyPoints,
                    matches, mask, 1.5, 20);
                if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                    homography = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(modelKeyPoints,
                        observedKeyPoints, matches, mask, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Using:**

```
var model = new Mat(@"image0.jpg");
var scene = new Mat(@"image1.jpg");
Mat result = new Mat();
VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
var matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch();
Mat mask;
Mat homography;
FindMatch(model, scene, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, matches, out mask, out homography);
CvInvoke.WarpPerspective(scene, result, homography, model.Size, Inter.Linear, Warp.InverseMap);
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to watch the process **use next code:**

```
public static Mat Draw(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage)
{
    Mat homography;
    VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
    VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
    using (VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch())
    {
        Mat mask;
        FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, matches, out mask, out homography);
        Mat result = new Mat();
        Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
            matches, result, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), mask);

        if (homography != null)
        {
            var imgWarped = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.WarpPerspective(observedImage, imgWarped, homography, modelImage.Size, Inter.Linear, Warp.InverseMap);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, modelImage.Size);
            var pts = new PointF[]
            {
                  new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom),
                  new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
                  new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
                  new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top)
            };

            pts = CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(pts, homography);
            var points = new Point[pts.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                points[i] = Point.Round(pts[i]);

            using (var vp = new VectorOfPoint(points))
            {
                CvInvoke.Polylines(result, vp, true, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 5);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Using:**

```
var model = new Mat(@"image0.jpg");
var scene = new Mat(@"image1.jpg");
var result = Draw(model, scene);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hey Codd, I have tried your code and works absolutely perfectly.