# Getting a 3D map on Meshlab with my disparity map

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction, disparity-mapping

I have a program that allows me to find the disparity map with 2 images from two non-stereocalibrated cameras. The disparity map looks good but when I add a piece of program to get a 3D map via meshlab, I get some scattered points (see photo result_clou.png)

On the other topics, I saw that I had to change the type and divide the disparity map by 16. I tried with a new map called disparity_SGBM2 as follows: disparity_SGBM2 = disparity_SGBM.astype(np.float32) / 16.0
I took a screenshot of the .ply with his error message (see result_disparity_SGBM2.png)

Does anyone have an idea how to unblock me please?
I also joined my python program below (because I can't send a python file) and the images used with the program (clou-l.png and clou-r.png).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read both images and convert to grayscale
img1 = cv.imread('clou-l.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv.imread('clou-r.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# PREPROCESSING

# Compare unprocessed images
#fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 10))
#axes[0].imshow(img1, cmap="gray")
#axes[1].imshow(img2, cmap="gray")
#axes[0].axhline(250)
#axes[1].axhline(250)
#axes[0].axhline(450)
#axes[1].axhline(450)
#plt.suptitle("Original images")
#plt.savefig("original_images.png")
#plt.show()

# 1. Detect keypoints and their descriptors
# Based on: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

# Visualize keypoints
imgSift = cv.drawKeypoints(
    img1, kp1, None, flags=cv.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
#cv.imshow("SIFT Keypoints", imgSift)
#cv.imwrite("sift_keypoints.png", imgSift)

# Match keypoints in both images
# Based on: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary
flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

# Keep good matches: calculate distinctive image features
# Lowe, D.G. Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints. International Journal of Computer Vision 60, 91–110 (2004). https://doi.org/10.1023/B:VISI.0000029664.99615.94
# https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf
matchesMask = [[0, 0] for i in range(len(matches))]
good = []
pts1 = []
pts2 = []

for i, (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        # Keep this keypoint pair
        matchesMask[i] = [1, 0]
        good.append(m)
        pts2.append(kp2[m.trainIdx].pt)
        pts1.append(kp1[m.queryIdx].pt)

# Draw the keypoint matches between both pictures
# Still based on: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html
draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0),
                   singlePointColor=(255, 0, 0),
                   matchesMask=matchesMask[300:500],
                   flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_DEFAULT)

keypoint_matches = cv.drawMatchesKnn(
    img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches[300:500], None, **draw_params)
#cv.imshow("Keypoint matches", keypoint_matches)
#cv.imwrite("keypoint_matches.png", keypoint_matches)


# ------------------------------------------------------------
# STEREO RECTIFICATION

# Calculate the fundamental matrix for the cameras
# https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html
pts1 = np.int32(pts1)
pts2 = np.int32(pts2)
fundamental_matrix, inliers = cv.findFundamentalMat(pts1, pts2, cv.FM_RANSAC)

# We select only inlier points
pts1 = pts1[inliers.ravel() == 1]
pts2 = pts2[inliers.ravel() == 1]

# Visualize epilines
# Adapted from: https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html


def drawlines(img1src, img2src, lines, pts1src, pts2src):
    ''' img1 - image on which we draw the epilines for the points in img2
        lines - corresponding epilines '''
    r, c = img1src.shape
    img1color = cv.cvtColor(img1src, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    img2color = cv.cvtColor(img2src, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    # Edit: use the same random seed so that two images are comparable!
    np.random.seed(0)
    for r, pt1, pt2 in zip(lines, pts1src, pts2src):
        color = tuple(np.random.randint(0, 255, 3).tolist())
        x0, y0 = map(int, [0, -r[2]/r[1]])
        x1, y1 = map(int, [c, -(r[2]+r[0]*c)/r[1]])
        img1color = cv.line(img1color, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), color, 1)
        img1color = cv.circle(img1color, tuple(pt1), 5, color, -1)
        img2color = cv.circle(img2color, tuple(pt2), 5, color, -1)
    return img1color, img2color


# Find epilines corresponding to points in right image (second image) and
# drawing its lines on left image
lines1 = cv.computeCorrespondEpilines(
    pts2.reshape(-1, 1, 2), 2, fundamental_matrix)
lines1 = lines1.reshape(-1, 3)
img5, img6 = drawlines(img1, img2, lines1, pts1, pts2)

# Find epilines corresponding to points in left image (first image) and
# drawing its lines on right image
lines2 = cv.computeCorrespondEpilines(
    pts1.reshape(-1, 1, 2), 1, fundamental_matrix)
lines2 = lines2.reshape(-1, 3)
img3, img4 = drawlines(img2, img1, lines2, pts2, pts1)

#plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img5)
#plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(img3)
#plt.suptitle("Epilines in both images")
#plt.savefig("epilines.png")
#plt.show()


# Stereo rectification (uncalibrated variant)
# Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62607343
h1, w1 = img1.shape
h2, w2 = img2.shape
_, H1, H2 = cv.stereoRectifyUncalibrated(
    np.float32(pts1), np.float32(pts2), fundamental_matrix, imgSize=(w1, h1)
)

# Rectify (undistort) the images and save them
# Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62607343
img1_rectified = cv.warpPerspective(img1, H1, (w1, h1))
img2_rectified = cv.warpPerspective(img2, H2, (w2, h2))
cv.imwrite("rectified_1.png", img1_rectified)
cv.imwrite("rectified_2.png", img2_rectified)

# Draw the rectified images
#fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 10))
#axes[0].imshow(img1_rectified, cmap="gray")
#axes[1].imshow(img2_rectified, cmap="gray")
#axes[0].axhline(250)
#axes[1].axhline(250)
#axes[0].axhline(450)
#axes[1].axhline(450)
#plt.suptitle("Rectified images")
#plt.savefig("rectified_images.png")
#plt.show()

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# CALCULATE DISPARITY (DEPTH MAP)
# Adapted from: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stereo_match.py
# and: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

# StereoSGBM Parameter explanations:
# https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d2/d85/classcv_1_1StereoSGBM.html

# Matched block size. It must be an odd number >=1 . Normally, it should be somewhere in the 3..11 range.
block_size = 11
min_disp = -128
max_disp = 128
# Maximum disparity minus minimum disparity. The value is always greater than zero.
# In the current implementation, this parameter must be divisible by 16.
num_disp = max_disp - min_disp
# Margin in percentage by which the best (minimum) computed cost function value should "win" the second best value to consider the found match correct.
# Normally, a value within the 5-15 range is good enough
uniquenessRatio = 5
# Maximum size of smooth disparity regions to consider their noise speckles and invalidate.
# Set it to 0 to disable speckle filtering. Otherwise, set it somewhere in the 50-200 range.
speckleWindowSize = 200
# Maximum disparity variation within each connected component.
# If you do speckle filtering, set the parameter to a positive value, it will be implicitly multiplied by 16.
# Normally, 1 or 2 is good enough.
speckleRange = 2
disp12MaxDiff = 0

stereo = cv.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity=min_disp,
    numDisparities=num_disp,
    blockSize=block_size,
    uniquenessRatio=uniquenessRatio,
    speckleWindowSize=speckleWindowSize,
    speckleRange=speckleRange,
    disp12MaxDiff=disp12MaxDiff,
    P1=8 * 1 * block_size * block_size,
    P2=32 * 1 * block_size * block_size,
)
disparity_SGBM = stereo.compute(img1_rectified, img2_rectified)
#disparity_SGBM2 = disparity_SGBM.astype(np.float32) / 16.0
#plt.imshow(disparity_SGBM, cmap='plasma')
#plt.colorbar()
#plt.show()

#Normalize the values to a range from 0..255 for a grayscale image
disparity_SGBM = cv.normalize(disparity_SGBM, disparity_SGBM, alpha=255,
                              beta=0, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX)
disparity_SGBM = np.uint8(disparity_SGBM)
#cv.imshow("Disparity", disparity_SGBM)
#cv.imwrite("disparity_SGBM_norm.png", disparity_SGBM)


#cv.waitKey()
#cv.destroyAllWindows()
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

"""That's the new part of the program for reconstructing the 3D map from the disparity map.
For seeing the 3D result, you need to open the clou.ply folder with Meshlab"""

def create_output(vertices, colors, filename):
    colors = colors.reshape(-1, 3)
    vertices = np.hstack([vertices.reshape(-1,3), colors])

    ply_header = '''ply
        format ascii 1.0
        element vertex %(vert_num)d
        property float x
        property float y
        property float z
        property uchar red
        property uchar green
        property uchar blue
        end_header
    '''

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(ply_header % dict(vert_num=len(vertices)))
        np.savetxt(f, vertices, '%f %f %f %d %d %d')

print("\nGenerating the 3D map ...")
h, w = img1.shape[:2]
focal_length = 0.8*w

#Perspective transformation matrix
Q = np.float32([[1, 0, 0, -w/2.0],
                [0,-1, 0,  h/2.0],
                [0, 0, 0, -focal_length],
                [0, 0, 1, 0]])


output_file = 'clou' + '.ply'
points_3D = cv.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity_SGBM, Q, handleMissingValues=0)
colors = cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask_map = disparity_SGBM > disparity_SGBM.min()
output_points = points_3D[mask_map]
output_colors = colors[mask_map]

print("\nCreating the output file ...\n")
create_output(output_points, output_colors, output_file)
```

[clou-l.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2VUB.jpg)

[clou-r.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhjCB.jpg)

[result_clou.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxqAL.png)

[result_disparity_SGBM2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBvA6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using very shiny objects, which are typically hard to match in stereo images and photogrammetry. You could try moving the illuminating lights, possibly to a more oblique angle, or fit polarizers over each lens, then illuminate with polarized light. Another technique you can employ is to cover the subject in white powder to create a matt/diffused surface, which can work better.

I've used DMAG (http://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/2013/04/depth-map-automatic-generator-dmag.html) to produce depth maps (with varying degrees of success) but it can produce intermediate files that firstly show the features it can find, then another step to show which features match between images. I've run your script to produce the rectified images to get an epipolar projection, then I ran those through DMAG. It shows very few matches, [Features L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D00AZ.jpg) [Features R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z94R.jpg) [Matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpTIu.jpg). With so few matches you're not going to produce much of a mesh.